# compare woocommerce product meta with customer meta, then hide/show products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, geolocation, show-hide

I have been trying to implement geolocation for woocommerce products on my store by displaying a specific category of products (rentals) only to customers within the city where the product is posted. For some reason, I do not want to use a plugin; also because I feel there is a way I can achieve this with a few lines of code. I tried to create a custom meta (product location)for each product, then compare this custom meta with logged-in user billing address. If they match, the product should be visible. Here is the code I was trying to put together, but nothing works so far.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'myshop_hide_product_if', 9999, 2 );
 
function myshop_hide_product_if( $q, $query ) {
 //product details 
 global $product;
    $product_id->get_id();
    $product_location = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'custom_product_location' );
    $product_category = array('rentals');
    //get user details

    $user = wp_get_current_user () ;
    $customer_city = ! empty( $user->ID ) ? get_user_meta( $user->ID , 'billing_state' , true ) : '' ;  
//hide em all 
    if ( $customer_city !== $product_location ) {
        $q->set( 'post__not_in', $product_category );
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the WC_Geolocation class to get the city if the user city is not set in the metadata.  There are also a few minor errors in your snippet. Like you don't actually assign `$product_id`

Also, I would hook this to the shop loop rather than the get products query. If you try to hook this into the get_products query, the global `$product` is not defined, so it would throw an error.

This hides the products, but doesn't update the query results. So this is a path to solving your problem.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop', 'myshop_hide_product_if', 20 );
function myshop_hide_product_if() {
    // product details.
    global $product;
    $product_id       = $product->get_id();
    $product_location = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'custom_product_location' );
    $product_category = array( 'rentals' );

    // get user details.
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( 0 < $user->ID ) {
        $customer_city = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'billing_state', true );
    } else {
        $ip            = WC_Geolocation::get_ip_address();
        $location      = WC_Geolocation::geolocate_ip( $ip );
        $customer_city = $location['state'];
    }
    // hide em all.
    if ( $customer_city !== $product_location ) {
        $product->set_catalog_visibility( 'hidden' );
    }
}
```